# Zome construction

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

I'm preparing a presentation on Penrose tiles, and I want to talk about how we can get non-periodic tilings of the plane by taking projections of slices of higher-dimensional periodic tilings (in particular, the Penrose tiles themselves can be gotten from the five-dimensional lattice $\lbrace (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5): x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5\in\mathbb{Z}\rbrace$). To explain this visually, I'd like to build a projection into 3 dimensions of a five-dimensional cube, using Zometool, but it's been a very long time since I've used Zome. Does anyone know where I can find instructions for doing this? I can't find any so far.

Thanks!